# How to use the Velocity Eclipse plug-in?

Tags: eclipse, liferay, velocity

I'm trying to create a theme plugin for Liferay with Velocity, but I'm having some problems. 
I'v installed the Velocity plug-in to Eclipse from here http://veloedit.sourceforge.net/updates/ . But I cant find it in Eclipse UI. How do I use it to edit Liferay velocity templates? Can you give some examples?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have installed the Velocity plugin, next you need to create your Liferay theme plugin.  This can be done with the [Liferay Plugins SDK](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/installing-the-sdk) and with the [Liferay IDE](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/installati-6).  Here is a tutorial for how to work with [Liferay themes](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/creating-liferay-them-7).  Once you have created your theme, you can customize any of the existing *.vtl files (velocity templates).  You just need to put these under the _diffs folder for the theme project, `_diffs/templates`.  Once you have copied a VTL file into the templates folder, you can edit it, by right-clicking the file in Eclipse and choosing "Open with > Velocity Editor".

Comment: There is NO "Velocity Editor" option.